# Union probability using pandas DataFrame

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, statistics

How would I go about finding the probability of being "Male" or "Voted for" in the most efficient way?

```
import pandas as pd
from pandas import DataFrame

df = DataFrame({"Voted for": {"Males": .22, "Females": .18},
                "Voted against" : {"Males": .33, "Females": .27},
                })
```

Gives:

```
In [219]: df
Out[219]:
         Voted against  Voted for
Females           0.27       0.18
Males             0.33       0.22
```

Answer (score 1):

Since `df.values.sum()` sums to 1 and the categories are mutually exclusive, you could compute the probability of "Males" or "Voted for" by subtracting from 1 the probability of "Females" and "Voted against":

```
In [23]: 1 - df.loc['Females', 'Voted against']
Out[23]: 0.72999999999999998
```

This is the most efficient way, given `df`, since it only requires one subtraction.